# Drupal 8 twig template creating issue in sum of content.field_output

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views, drupal-8, drupal-templates

I am doing some customization in my views-view-table.html.twig file i would like to add content.field_output values

My code is

```
{% set f_v = content.field_output * 1 %}
{{ f_v }}
```

Or

```
{% set f_v = content.field_output + 1 %}
{{ f_v }}
```

Both code are not working

Comment: define not working?

Comment: define is working but is returning an object rather than a string how can i convert value or get a raw value ?

Comment: you might have more luck making calculations in a preprocess function in PHP instead of twig.
in any case the variable content.field_output contains a renderable element en not just an integer. You could use the 'raw' filter but that is discouraged since the output is not sanitized.